# Siri - Shortcuts on the iPhone: App isn't visible in the suggestions

Tags: iphone, sirishortcuts

I want to add a shortcut in the shortcut app on my iPhone. My aim is to create a shortcut to open an folder in a app. But this app isn't visible in the suggestions. Does anyone know why I can't see this app? It is already installed on the iPhone.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. If it is, please [edit] your question and clarify. If not, please delete this question and consider posting in a more appropriate place such as [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just googled your problem and found the procedure. Please have a look.
https://www.igeeksblog.com/siri-app-suggestions-not-working-in-ios-10/

Comment: If the link has a good solution to this person's question, you should post the relevant parts of it as an answer, so that it exists on this site for others to use.